# Custom Preference with AndroidX Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

Before AndroidX,

I would override the Preference's `onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)` method to pass Custom Layouts to be used as Preference.

But in AndroidX's Preference, there is no `onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)` method but it instead has `onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder)`, I am not sure how to pass custom layouts & use them instead..

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to assign it in the constructor already:

```
this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preferences);
```

Here are some examples for [onBindViewHolder()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder).

Comment: hey there, thanks for the Answer, it works but partially in case of CheckBoxPreference.. I mean, I see two checkboxes, one from my layout & one from android's layout.. Any method or idea on how to hide the second checkbox?

Comment: @DarShan try to extend `Preference` instead of `CheckBoxPreference`... this would require binding the events manually, but there would be no other checkbox. and even if, the issue might be adding the second one checkbox, not the one which is already present there (the other way around). `viewHolder.findViewById()` generaly works; also `viewHolder.itemView`.

Comment: thanks for the idea Martin but I ended up passing a CheckBox layout in `setWidgetResourceLayout()` instead which works fine.